# passing data from server to ionic app

Tags: javascript, php, ionic-framework, httprequest, ionic2

i'm developing an hybrid app with ionic 2 and i must pass data from server (PHP files) to ionic app.
I know that i must use an HTTP request for passing data between server and app, i searched on the web and i found an example of code that work for me, but the problem is that this code print from the server to the app using the function "echo" and i would to pass the value of the variable to the app and AFTER because i need to modify it.

This is the code:

Form in ionic app:

```
    <ion-content padding="true">
        <form ng-submit="submit()">
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label">username</span>
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="enter username" ng-model="data.username">
            </label>

            <input class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit to server">                    
        </form>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                Response: <b ng-bind="response"></b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
```

controller in app.js:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.submit = function(){
        var link = 'http://localhost/ShuttleFIX/api.php';

        $http.post(link, {username : $scope.data.username}).then(function (res){
            $scope.response = res.data;
        });
    };
});
```

PHP file on the server:

```
 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
 if (isset($postdata)) {
 $request = json_decode($postdata);
 $username = $request->username;

 if ($username != "") {
 echo "Server returns: " . $username;
 }
 else {
 echo "Empty username parameter!";
 }
 }
 else {
 echo "Not called properly with username parameter!";
 }
```

Can someone help me?

Thank's

Comment: Not clear what you want.. use json to send and receive data.. Explain a bit more..

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
 if ($username != "") {
    json_encode(array("result"=>$username));
 }
 else {
    json_encode(array("result"=>"No Data"));
 }
 }
 else {
    json_encode(array("result"=>"Not called properly with username parameter!"));
 }
```

Now in controller..

```
$scope.username = response[0].result
```

Now you can write your logic using `$scope.username`.

You need to send `json` data to app also..

Comment: thank's, i'm trying it, only one question, if i want print the username to the app must i change this line "Response: <b ng-bind="response"></b>" changing response with username? Thank's

Comment: ok, there is an error in the code that you have wrote, the console tell me this: TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined

Comment: can you show what response is coming .. in developer tools ? Open developer tools `ctrl+shift+j` go to network and make request... now see the request and click on it.. then go to response tab.. it will show the response received.

Comment: "This request has no response data available"